# How to Add Student_ID to Devise Confirmation Email To Be Emailed to User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a rails application where a user needs its student_id to access some features.

The default devise confirmation email is this

```
<p>Welcome <%= @email %>!</p>

<p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>

<p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @resource.confirmation_token) %></p>
```

I want to know where the

```
<%= @email %>
```

is from ?

I tried adding

```
<p>Your student id is <%= @student_id %> ! Please don't forget ! </p>
```

but it did not work.

I have this in my routes

```
devise_for :students
```

then a `link_to to the new_student_registration path`  in application.html.erb and then a simple_form in that registration view under devise, after a user signs up the user will get a confirmation email sent by sendgrid.

My question is won't that particular student's record be exposed during the sequence from above? and hence that is where the

`<%= @email %>` comes from?

why can't I pass in the student id to be emailed as well?

Answer (score 0):

You should override default email template which lives in `app/views/users/mailer/confirmation_email.html.erb` (and so do `reset_password_instructions.html.erb` and `unlock_instructions.html.erb`) if you want to change those emails. Just add that file to your app and devise should use it instead of default one.

You can also generate these views with `rails g devise:views`.